# How can I set minDate + 17hours in flatpickr

Tags: javascript, date, flatpickr

I'm creating a form with Fluentforms and it has inside a datetime field.

I would like to allow users to pick a date only 17 hours before the "departure".

So I need something like today + 17hours.

At first I've added today + 2 days

```
{
    minDate:  new Date().fp_incr(2)
}
```

But my client wants it + 17 hours.

I have seen that on flatpickr I should be able to use **hourIncrement** but i'm not really sure how to use it exactly.

I have tried also with this code but it's not working

```
    function addHours(date, hours) {
    const hoursToAdd = hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + hoursToAdd);
    return date;
}

var newDate = addHours(new Date(),17);
```

Can someone please help me?